# Migrating from Maven to SBT

Tags: java, scala, maven, pom.xml, sbt

As you know, SBT is compatible with Maven in some way -- SBT recognizes simple Maven POMs and can use dependencies and repositories specified in them. However, [SBT wiki](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LibraryManagement) says that, if inline dependency is specified in SBT project definition, POM will be ignored (so using both in this case is impossible):

> Maven and Ivy configurations (pom.xml
> and ivy.xml) are ignored when inline
> dependency declarations are present.

Does anyone know, if any kind of converter from Maven POM to SBT project definition exists (translating POM's XML into project definition Scala code)? I'm considering writing such script (that will help to migrate my old Scala/Maven projects to SBT), but want to know first, if this functionality already exists.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Converter is far too strong a term for this hack, but I wrote a script to take a block of `<dependencies>` and output SBT style deps: http://gist.github.com/388334

Comment: Nice hack! I was thinking about this kind of stuff (+ conversion of properties and repos).

Answer (score 20):

All the tips above had the issue for me that properties were not resolved, and as we make heavy use of the dependencyManagement from parent poms, I was hoping for something that actually could fully understand maven.  I whipped together a simplistic scriptlet that outputs the dependencies from maven and just takes the top level items and then does a simple regex for the group, artifact, version, and scope (the artifact type is ignored)

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep "] +" | perl -pe 's/.*\s([\w\.\-]+):([\w\.\-]+):\w+:([\w\.\-]+):(\w+).*/libraryDependencies += "$1" % "$2" % "$3" % "$4"\n /'
```

I piped this directly to project/build.sbt.  The sample output is (remember to keep empty spaces between sbt lines)

```
libraryDependencies += "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "3.1.0.RELEASE" % "compile"

libraryDependencies += "se.scalablesolutions.akka" % "akka-actor" % "1.3.1" % "compile"

libraryDependencies += "se.scalablesolutions.akka" % "akka-spring" % "1.3.1" % "compile"
```

Comment: Totally helpful, nice

Answer (score 6):

Not a converter, but a step-by-step guide for moving a multimodule project from Maven to SBT can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170428212050/http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/01/04/maven-to-sbt).

Quite nice for understanding what actually happens and ensuring you have a fair amount of control over the proces..

Comment: That link is dead :(

Answer (score 5):

I didn't manage to find an undocumented capability in SBT that allows to make such conversions (POM -> project definition), and have came up with writing [a very simple script](http://code.google.com/p/vrblog/source/browse/trunk/src/main/scala/com/vasilrem/sbt/pomtopm/PomToPm.scala) that creates [SBT build file](http://pastie.org/992782) with repos/dependencies from [POM](http://code.google.com/p/kandash/source/browse/modules/kandash/kandash-service/pom.xml).

In case you just need to convert Maven/XML dependencies into SBT/Scala, you can use [this script](http://gist.github.com/388334) provided by [@retronym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160378/retronym)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [mvn2sbt](https://github.com/ajozwik/mvn2sbt) project for convertion java maven project to sbt project.

Comment: Very cool - a great way to get things up and (nearly) running!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look a CodaHale's Maven-SBT project over at Git-Hub. Basically, CodaHale has swapped out IVY from SBT and replaced it with Maven, so POM related tasks *should* be be more compatible/flexible.

Comment: the link seems to be dead, please use this one: https://github.com/rossabaker/maven-sbt

Answer (score 1):

I wrote yet another hack to convert between `pom.xml` and `build.sbt`.  It's useful for converting the bulk of what I'm interested in.

https://gist.github.com/schmmd/5050790

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and created a solution in javascript that you can access here:
 http://www.maven-to-sbt.de/